# How to run a simple project imported with SVN?

Tags: java

I have to run a project developed in java by someone else  using eclipse. I've imported this project with SVN and the problem is that it's not a Java project so I did not find a way to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the other person committed the `src` folder and other folders which contain source for the project but no IDE configuration files, you could create an empty project with your IDE of choice and then import the files you have downloaded from SVN there.

If this is not the case, you will need to provide more information.